# Row id not being passed properly to the modal popup

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core

Ok I have an issue with my table its only getting the first records id passed to it. When I click the delete button the value

```
<table class="table table-dark">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Circuit name    </th>
        <th scope="col">Resistance </th>
        <th scope="col">Circuit type</th>
        <th scope="col">Passed</th>
        <th scope="col">Action </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        var idx = 0;
        var tm = "#myModal" + item.Id;
        var mid = "myModal" + item.Id;
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </th>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Resitance)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CirtcutType)</td>

        <td>
            @(item.Passed? "Yes": "No")

        </td>


        <td>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myEditModal"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit</button>


            <button type="button" data-id="@item.Id" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" data-target="#deleteLink">
                <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                Delete
            </button>



            @{Html.RenderPartial("EditFormPartial",Model.Where(w=>w.Id==item.Id).FirstOrDefault());}


            <div id="deleteLink" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Electrician", FormMethod.Post)) {
                        <!-- Modal content-->
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Record!</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                Are you sure you wish to delete this record ?.
                                <!--this is how to pass the id through-->
                                <input type="text" name="linkId" value="@item.Id" />

                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">

                                <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-danger"
                                        onclick="$('#testForm').submit()">
                                    Yes
                                </button>
                                <button class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
```

The value here is only ever showing the first record id value of 15

```
 <input type="text" name="linkId" value="@item.Id" />
```

This is the javascript. How Do I ensure that im getting each id and not just the first one.

```
<script>
  $('#deleteLink').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var dataId = $(this).attr("data-id");

});

function deleteConfirm()
{
    var url = "@Url.Action("Delete", "Electrician")/" + $("#Id").val();
    $.post(url).success(function () {
        location.href = "@Url.Action("Index", "Electrician")";
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to add a js function and pass the `@item.Id` to the function like below:

```
@model IEnumerable<Electrician>
<table class="table table-dark">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Circuit name    </th>
            <th scope="col">Resistance </th>
            <th scope="col">Circuit type</th>
            <th scope="col">Passed</th>
            <th scope="col">Action </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            var idx = 0;
            var tm = "#myModal" + item.Id;
            var mid = "myModal" + item.Id;
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </th>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Resitance)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CirtcutType)</td>
                <td>
                    @(item.Passed ? "Yes" : "No")
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" onclick="deleteModal(@item.Id)" data-id="@item.Id" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" data-target="#deleteLink">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        Delete
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>           
        }
    </tbody>
</table>  
<div id="deleteLink" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Electrician", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Record!</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Are you sure you wish to delete this record ?.
                    <!--this is how to pass the id through-->
                    <input type="text" name="linkId"  id="linkId"/>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">

                    <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-danger"
                            onclick="$('#testForm').submit()">
                        Yes
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>                  
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        function deleteModal(id) {
            $("#linkId").val(id);
        }
    </script>
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: is it easy to have the same dialog do edit and new functions what be best way to do that